# Showing object names in a listbox?

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

I'm trying to show my object names in a listbox, but couldn't make it in a good way. I might probably declare all the names manually but I want to make it by showing my object names as datasource. Couldn't find out how to do it. I wonder if I should make a list or if there is any easy way to show my object names in a list. Probably a foreach loop would fix it easily but I can't find out how to just choose names and add it in the listbox.

My code looks like this:

```
class Platform
{

public string name, action, adventure, rpg, simulation, strategy, casual, audianceY, audianceE, audianceM;

        public Platform(string nameIn, string actionIn, string adventureIn, string rpgIn, string simulationIn, string strategyIn, string casualIn, string audianceYIn, string audianceEIn, string audianceMIn)
        {
            name = nameIn;
            action = actionIn;
            adventure = adventureIn;
            rpg = rpgIn;
            simulation = simulationIn;
            strategy = strategyIn;
            casual = casualIn;
            audianceY = audianceYIn;
            audianceM = audianceMIn;
            audianceE = audianceEIn;
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return name;
        }

}



public partial class Main : Form
    {

        public Main()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Main_Load_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            //---------------------------------
            // Platform List
            //---------------------------------

            Platform PC = new Platform("PC", "++", "+++", "++", "+++", "+++", "---", "+", "++", "+++");
            Platform G64 = new Platform("G64", "++", "+++", "++", "++", "+++", "--", "+", "++", "+++");
            Platform TES = new Platform("TES", "+", "--", "+", "+", "--", "+++", "+++", "++", "---");

         }


          foreach (???)
          {
          listBox1.Items.Add(???)
          }

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code won't compile as-is, so I'll just assume you meant to include the `foreach` loop inside the `Main_Load` event.

It'd be far easier if you added all the new Platform instances to a list, rather than individual variables. You could then set the list as the DataSource, and specify what the display/value members should be.

```
private void Main_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var platforms = new List<Platform> {
        new Platform("PC", "++", "+++", "++", "+++", "+++", "---", "+", "++", "+++"),
        new Platform("G64", "++", "+++", "++", "++", "+++", "--", "+", "++", "+++"),
        new Platform("TES", "+", "--", "+", "+", "--", "+++", "+++", "++", "---")
    };

    listBox1.DataSource = platforms;
    listBox1.DisplayMember = "name";
    listBox1.ValueMember = "name";
}
```

To bind to "name", you'll need to change it to a property: (or you'll get an `ArgumentException`)

```
public string name { get; set; }
```

A couple thoughts:

- If you want to reuse those Platforms, you'll have to declare them outside of the method.
- It's more typical to create public properties with getters/setters than public fields like you're currently doing, and to capitalize them too, like this:

  ```
  public string Name { get; set; }
  ```

Comment: Thank you for the recommendations, I will keep all in mind :) By the way, the only thing that is not working is listBox1.ItemsSource thing. Getting error message that it's not containing ItemsSource extension method

Comment: Well it is, I have no idea what I'm missing, being newbie sucks :)

Comment: on valuemember it says

Argumentexception was unhandled
"An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll"

Comment: Oh alright, but if I use get/setters instead of a field, can I still declare them in the same way? Like:

new Platform("PC", "++", "+++", "++", "+++", "+++", "---", "+", "++", "+++")

? Or do I have to declare them each?